# What is the proper way to copy InventTable in ax 2012?

Tags: axapta

In previous versions, there was InventTable and InventTableModule(there were more but they often could be ignored), so copying an an item was easy with `buf2buf` and replacing itemId.

In ax2012 there are dozens of Eco* tables all over the place so copying them all would is much more error prone (easier to forget something).

What's proper way to copy an item with all its attributes values? Manual copy of tables? Axd classes? Ax classes? Some other mechanism?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to copy product in AX2012, you need to write your own code to manage it. The way is depends on your task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there aren't any classes available that allow you to copy an item out of the box so you'll have to write your own code to copy all the data.

I agree the new table structure makes it a bit cumbersome but you could start with the code as explained in [this blog post](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axwonders/archive/2013/03/22/copy-set-delete-get-product-categories-and-attributes-in-ax-2012-x)

Basically the class allows you to

- Copy product attributes and categories
- Delete product attributes
- Get product attributes
- Set product attributes

Needless to say you will have to review the code to see if it meets all your requirements, but it could be a good starting point